# How to bypass menu link access permission

Tags: 8

I have added some links from the admin page to a menu, but these links are not displayed in anonymous.
Certainly anonymous doesn't have access permission to the links, but I want to display the menu.
is there a hook or something that bypass access permission?
Thank you.

Comment: Drupal first verifies the user has access to the linked pages. If the user doesn't have access to those pages, the links aren't shown. It would not make sense to show a link for which the user gets a 403 error when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: I have added another module that redirects user to the login page when anonymous visits restricted pages.
So I want to display a link even on a page that user doesn't have permission.

Comment: Render the menu tree without `menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293080/why-cache-tags-is-different-if-i-am-logged

Comment: I have created a menu block referring to the following link. 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/group/menu/8.8.x#sec_rendering
Overriding the existing menu seems difficult, but I could do what I expected.
Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your menu links as `/user/login?destination=/my-path` and that will mean authenticated users would get taken to `/user/login` but then instantly redirection to `/my-path` because they're already logged in

Anonymous users will see the menu links and be taken to the login page if they tried to click them

Answer (score 1):

I have created a menu block referring to the following link.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/group/menu/8.8.x#sec_rendering
And by placing that block in the block layout, I achieved my purpose.